# How to check my sync status on Geth 1.5.5, Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, raspberry-pi

Have a Geth 1.5.5 node running on a raspberry pi 3.  When I type in

```
sudo systemctl status geth
```

I'll get ever changing time and block information.  Neat, but how do I know when I am synced up?  Is there another sudo command I should do?

Answer (score 59):

Continuing to research, need to enter the geth node console to enter special commands.  The following works:

```
geth attach
```

Sends user to the geth node console.

```
eth.syncing
```

Produces a result like current block: 82,100; highest block 2,910,032.

```
exit
```

To go back to Pi prompt.

Comment: when I am typing `eth.syncing` just getting `false` printed

Comment: Wait a few seconds and it will prompt a result

Comment: @Coren you can wait forever

Comment: You pretty much need a supercomputer to run Ethereum nowadays.

Comment: geth syntax for windows: `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`

Comment: @sreginogemoh `false` means you are fully synced already (technically just means that it is not syncing actually so I suppose maybe it could also mean you aren't syncing for some reason other than being fully sync'd ... hmmmm)

Comment: @sreginogemoh false is good. It means you are up to date with the latest block and fully synched. It's stupidly counterintuitive as a user message but literally true: You are not syncing, you are synched.

Answer (score 49):

After running your normal geth --fast command you can open a new window and run the "geth attach" command as this will attach you to the javascript interface

```
$ geth attach
```

Then you can use this script to have a nice output of what is happening. It is very rudimentary but works really well to give you an idea of how long you will still need to wait. First wait 10 seconds (as the first ETA is incorrect) then after the second display of estimates you will start to see the actual numbers.

```
var lastPercentage = 0;var lastBlocksToGo = 0;var timeInterval = 10000;
setInterval(function(){
    var percentage = eth.syncing.currentBlock/eth.syncing.highestBlock*100;
    var percentagePerTime = percentage - lastPercentage;
    var blocksToGo = eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock;
    var bps = (lastBlocksToGo - blocksToGo) / (timeInterval / 1000)
    var etas = 100 / percentagePerTime * (timeInterval / 1000)

    var etaM = parseInt(etas/60,10);
    console.log(parseInt(percentage,10)+'% ETA: '+etaM+' minutes @ '+bps+'bps');

    lastPercentage = percentage;lastBlocksToGo = blocksToGo;
},timeInterval);
```

This will give you an output similar to this:

```
85% ETA: 573 minutes @ 134.4bps
86% ETA: 533 minutes @ 144.3bps
86% ETA: 442 minutes @ 173.9bps
```

Comment: Hello, this helps me a lot to see the ETAs being continuously printed in the terminal. I would choose this as the answer if I were to ask the question.

Comment: Or like this: 99% ETA: 399672 minutes @ 0.2bps
99% ETA: 399672 minutes @ 0.2bps
99% ETA: 399672 minutes @ 0.2bps
99% ETA: 399672 minutes @ 0.2bps
99% ETA: 399672 minutes @ 0.2bps
Ethereum is dead to me.

Comment: @Dagelf you're probably "stuck" on state trie syncing. read more about in this issue https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15001#issuecomment-370732526 (find comments by maintainer **karalabe**)

Comment: This works well, but I've noticed that block sync times vary *a lot*. I've synced multiple times in parity and while for a long time block times were at around 1-2blocks per second for multiple hours (ETA of 100 days), but then it finished over night anyways

Comment: its gives me an empty set `{}`

Comment: @Dagelf RIP, my friend.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you will need to connect to the running geth process from a second terminal

```
$ geth attach
```

As the other answers have stated the structure you are interested is eth.syncing

To see the remaining blocks you could do

```
> eth.syncing.highestBlock - eth.syncing.currentBlock
```

And for the remaining states

```
> eth.syncing.knownStates - eth.syncing.pulledStates
```

Answer (score 3):

While running geth sync process, I used `geth attach` and then used `eth.syncing` on geth console.

[image: eth.syncing on "geth attach" console.]

I could get block info. And if you're just after running `geth` command itself, you need to wait until geth starts "real" syncing process. Otherwise you'll see `false`.

`geth version` result

```
Geth
Version: 1.7.2-stable
Git Commit: 1db4ecdc0b9e828ff65777fb466fc7c1d04e0de9
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.9.1
Operating System: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9.1/libexec
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [web3.eth.syncing](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsyncing), i.e.:

```
server:~# geth attach
> web3.eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4504031,
  highestBlock: 4660759,
  knownStates: 31357681,
  pulledStates: 31357680,
  startingBlock: 4504031
}
```

Or the same as above but `async` using [getSyncing](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsyncing):

```
web3.eth.getSyncing(callback(error, result){ ... })
```

Answer (score -1):

Eth syncing percent:

```
eth.syncing.currentBlock * 100 / eth.syncing.highestBlock
```

Comment: That formula works when you are syncing in full mode. In fast mode a large part is downloading states and the formula doesn't take that into account.